# Changing the default method parameters IntelliJ creates

Tags: java, configuration, intellij-idea, code-generation

I'd like to change the default generated parameters by IntelliJ when I ask it to automatically create a method.

For example if I write the following (it's just an example, this question isn't about using *List* instead of *ArrayList*), before the method *generate()* is created:

```
generate( new ArrayList<String>{}, 42 );
```

and ask IntelliJ to create the method, it creates this:

```
private void generate( ArrayList<String> strings, int i ) {
}
```

But I'd like to have this instead:

```
private void generate(
    @NotNull final ArrayList<String> strings,
    final int i
) {
}
```

In other words I'd like:

- every primitive to be preceded by the *final* keyword
- every non primitive to be preceded by the *final* keyword
- every non primitive to be preceded by the *@NotNull* annotation
- (ideally) every parameter to go on its own line

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go into the settings and have a look at the code formatting for most of this.

I'm not sure about the `@NotNull` or `final` choices.

UPDATE: I think @NotNull annotation will show up if you tell IntelliJ that you want JDK 6 or higher language features.  This means that you have to compile with JDK 6 or higher, of course.

The rest should be under code style settings.  Or file or method templates.

Comment: thanks, I did find a *"Make generated parameters final"* option in *Settings* / *Code Generation*.  Still looking for the rest : )